# Pygame window not loading

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

When I compile my code there are no errors but the pygame window doesn't pop up even though the code compiles. I just keep getting the "Hello from the pygame community" message. I tried running other programs and my version of pygame still works.

```
import pygame
import os

class Application:
     def __init__(self):
         self.isRunning = True
         self.displaySurface = None 
         self.fpsClock = None 
         self.attractors = []
         self.size = self.width, self.height = 1920, 1080 
         
         pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of changes to be made:

1. `self.displaySurface` should be equal to `pygame.display.set_mode(self.size)`

```py
self.displaySurface = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size) #Making the screen
```

(Note that you need to move the line `self.size = (self.width, self.height) = 1920, 1080` above `self.displaySurface = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size)`, so that you can use `self.size`  in `self.displaySurface = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size)`)

2. You need to use a while loop to keep check of all the events taking place on the game screen and to update the screen at every single frame

```py
while self.isRunning:
     for event in pygame.event.get():#Get all the events
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:#If the users closes the program by clicking the 'X' button
             pygame.quit()#De-initialise pygame
             sys.exit()#Quit the app
     pygame.display.update() #Update the screen
```

3. To execute the `__init__` method of the class you need to create an object

```py
app = Application()#Creating an object
```

So the final code should look somewhat like:

```py
import pygame
import os
import sys

class Application:

     def __init__(self):
         pygame.init()
         self.isRunning = True
         self.size = (self.width, self.height) = 1920, 1080 #A tuple
         self.displaySurface = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size) #Making the screen
         self.fpsClock = None 
         self.attractors = []
          
         while True:
             for event in pygame.event.get():#Get all the events
                 if event.type == pygame.QUIT:#If the user closes the program by clicking the 'X' button
                     pygame.quit()#De-initialise pygame
                     sys.exit()#Quit the app
             pygame.display.update() #Update the screen

app = Application()#Creating an object
```